# Using grep and xargs with git to delete multiple branches at once

Tags: git, cmd, grep, xargs

I've been using some of the Linux tooling on my Windows machine for a little while now, since it comes with the git installation and it's a ton of fun to use. I've been particularly enamored with this command, which should theoretically allow me to delete all my extraneous git branches in one go:

```bash
git branch | grep -v 'master' | xargs git branch -d
```

A while ago, however, this stopped working. Instead I get a series of error messages for each branch along the following lines:

```
error: branch 'extraneous-branch-1?' not found.
error: branch 'extraneous-branch-2?' not found.
error: branch 'extraneous-branch-3?' not found.
...
```

Note that the question marks are not part of my branch names - those are apparently being added somehow  when the values are piped from grep to xargs. When I run xargs in interactive mode to try to see what it's actually producing, I get an output that looks like this:

```
git branch -d 'extraneous-branch-1'$'\r' 'extraneous-branch-2'$'\r' 'extraneous-branch-3'$'\r' ...
```

It seems as if grep is piping the end-of-line and carriage-return entries as part of each match, though I don't know how to prevent it from doing that. What baffles me is that I definitely remember this working before - I have no idea what would have changed. Truthfully I know barely anything about the Linux command line tools, so I wouldn't be surprised if there's something obvious I'm overlooking here. Appreciate any advice either way.

**Edit**

When I run `git branch | cat -A`, I get the following result:

```
 extraneous-branch-1$
 extraneous-branch-2$
 extraneous-branch-3$
```

Comment: Can you show output of `git branch | cat -A` ?

Comment: Interesting. I'll update my post with the results I got.

Comment: It's not `+ cat`, it's pipe: `|`. Fixed.

Comment: ok now try: `git branch | command grep -vF 'master' | cat -A`

Comment: Ah rats, it appears I don't have `command` - when I try that I get `'command' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Oh heck. You pointed me in the right direction, though - I tried this and it worked: `git branch | grep -v master | cat | xargs git branch -d`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to anubhava for pointing me in the right direction here. It appears grep is returning a bunch of non-printing characters that are visible when you run `git branch | cat -A`. It turns out just adding `cat` in there eliminates all those characters. Now it works perfectly.

```bash
git branch | grep -v master | cat | xargs git branch -d
```

A bit more verbose than before, but I'm not complaining.

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem here is a specific example of a more general case: some Git commands produce output that is meant for a *human* to read, and other Git commands produce output that is meant for a *computer* to read.  Reading human output with computer programs produces surprises, so: don't do that.

In particular, `git branch` may add *color encoding* to branch names, or run its output through a *pager* that does fancy things.  This is because `git branch` is what Git calls a *porcelain* command, meaning it produces human-readable output.  Fortunately, there's a similar *plumbing* command, `git for-each-ref`, that—because it is "plumbing"—produces computer-readable output by default.

The `for-each-ref` command is a little trickier to use because you must be more explicit.  To get *branch names*, without further details, you need:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads
```

You can run this output through `grep -v '^master$'` to drop the name `master`.  (Your existing grep is a little loose.  It would also drop, e.g., the branch name `stairmaster_bugfix`.)

For more on the `git for-each-ref` command, see [its documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref).  Note that by default, `git branch` *attempts* to drop fancy features like colorization and use of the pager by default if its stdout is not a "tty device" as determined by the C library [`isatty`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/isatty.html) function, but you can override these defaults with configuration settings.  It is likely that you have done this, since `git branch | grep` generally causes the C library `isatty` to say "no, not a tty".